# Margin on body not being overwritten?

Tags: css, margin

I have a fixed div at the top of my page, yet for some reason there is a gap above it when it should be flush with the top of the screen.

On inspecting the HTML I have found that body seems to have a margin-top of 8px. I implemented normalize.css to clear up the problem (as it's useful later on anyway) and now in my Chrome tools it is showing up as being overwritten (margin-top:8px has been striked out and normalize.css margin:0; is not) however it doesn't seem to be making any change to the design?

Can be found here:

http://www.haselden.co.uk/james/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this style for #navigation:

```
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/stripes_bg.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Can you explain a little more about this solution? Why was it that my margin was not working? I see you have implemented top:0 on this solution whereas I had margin-top:0

Comment: position: fixed; makes the element take up a fixed position within the view frame.  You can use the top/left/bottom/right css properties to set where in the view frame the fixed element appears.  IE - if you want your fixed element in the top right corner you can use top: 0; right: 0; and if you want it in the bottom left you can use bottom: 0; left: 0;

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` in `#wrapper #top` had a margin that was pushing the `#wrapper` down, creating margin that pushed down the `#navigation` element, too.  If you remove that `top-margin` from the `h1`, everything will slide up like you want.